# CakePHP1.3でビューを共通化する方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHP1.3でAPIの開発しています。
ビューには下記のようにjson_encodeが1行書かれているのみです。

```
 echo json_encode($result);
```

すべてのAPIビューは同じ内容を書くので、ビューファイルを共通化したいと考えました。
アクションにrender()を書くとビューファイルを共通化できました。

```
$this->render(null, null, VIEWS . "api.json");
```

しかし、これでは全てのアクションに上記の記述を書かなければなりません。
そこで、app_controller.phpなどにビューの指定をまとめて記述する方法があるかを教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

アクション毎に特別な設定を行わずAppController等で共通化するのであれば、次の2つのやり方が考えられます。

1. 2.x系のJsonViewを移植し、`AppController::beforeFilter()`でビュークラスを切り替える。
2. `AppController::beforeRender()`で、レンダリングを行い終了させる。

1の方が望ましいと考えますが、ここではより簡易にできる2の方法を示します。

`app/config/routes.php`に追加

```
Router::parseExtensions();
```

`app/app_controller.php`

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('RequestHandler', // ... (他にあれば追記) );

    // (...snip...)

    public function beforeRender() {
        if ($this->RequestHandler->ext === 'json') {
            // リクエストされたURLの拡張子がjsonであれば
            Configure::write('debug', 0);
            // レンダリング
            $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json');
            $View = new View($this);
            echo $View->render('/json/default');
            // 終了処理
            $this->_stop();
        }
    }

    // (...snip...)

}
```

`app/view/json/default.ctp`

```
<?php
echo json_encode($result, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

これで、`/foo/bar.json` のようなURLでアクセスされた場合に、`app/view/json/default.ctp`でレンダリングされるようになります。

Comment: なお、CakePHP 1.3系は既にサポートを終了していますので、2系または3系の利用を強くお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変ためになりました。
けっこうソースに書き込みをしないといけないのですね。仰るとおりで早くCakePHP1.3から卒業をしたいと考えていますm(_ _)m